# Start menu content has disappeared after reinstalling C: partition

Tags: windows-7, windows, formatting, start-menu

I have *Windows 7 64bit* with 2 partitions: 
  *C:*, which is system partition (**~100GB**)
  *D:* partition (**~600GB**) for programs

[I've changed in **Windows Registry** default directory for new installed software, which is: **D:/Program Files** for 64 bit software and respectively: **D:/Program Files (x86)** for 32 bit software.]

Unfortunately I needed to reinstall *Windows 7* (only *C:* partition). After reinstalling it I figure out that I have nothing in *Start Menu*. *Windows Registry* was propably also cleared and I expect that I may have problems with programs installed on D: partition which may assume that they have already made changes in **Registry** (which is actually true, they did it, but I've formated C: and propably *Windows Registry* was simultaneously cleared).

I want my *Start Menu* content back. How can I deal with it?

Comment: You have to reinstall all of your programs. Doesn't matter that they are on the D drive; your new Windows installation knows nothing about them.

Comment: So I am assuming the question you have is how can you restore those program shortcuts and settings? If so I believe it would be easier to just re-install the applications. Or, you could start using portable versions of those apps whenever possible so that you won't need to re-install most of them whenever you need to format.

Comment: When you get everything re-installed, make an image of your c: drive, using Norton Ghost or something similar.  Restoring from the ghost image will retain all of your program settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall your programs I'm afraid.

You may have moved your programs to a different partition, but by reinstalling C: - you've blanked and rebuilt the OS.  Your new OS doesn't know about your programs - to the new version of windows, they're just files on a drive.

The reason for this is that when you reinstalled your OS, you blanked your registry.. which sits on C: and is where your application list is hosted along with a lot of config info needed to launch various programs.